# Select is not working for the newly added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code , when you select the opt1 the opt2 will change appropriate. But in the newly added row ( row will add when you click on the Add row button)., is not generating the proper options in opt2.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://web-86d95219-b398-4432-85a8-fae716ac3a54.runnablecodesnippets.com/css/datepicker.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://web-86d95219-b398-4432-85a8-fae716ac3a54.runnablecodesnippets.com/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
     <tr >
      <th class="text-center">
       #
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Name
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Mail
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Mobile
      </th>      <th class="text-center">
       Mobile
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      <input id = "date0" type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
                   <select name="category" class="input category">                    <option value = "Week">Week</option>
                    <option selected value = "Month">Month</option>
                    <option value = "Year">Year</option></select>
      </td><td>
                   <select name="sub_category" class="input sub_category"></select>
      </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $(document).on("click", "#add_row", function(){
        var datepic = "#date" + i;
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input id = 'date"+
          i+"'  name='name" + i + 
          "' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'/>" 
          + "</td><td><input  name='mail" + 
          i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'>"
          +"</td><td><select class='input category'><option value ='Week'>Week</option><option value = 'Month'>Month</option><option value ='Year'>Year</option></select></select>"
          +"</td>"+"</td><td><select class='input sub_category'></select>"
          +"</td>");

        $(datepic).datepicker();

         $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++; 
     });

     $(document).on("click","#delete_row", function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });
$(document).on("click",".category", function(){
 var new_category = $(".category").val();
        var temp = '{"Week": ["2014-02-24", "2014-02-17", "2011-01-03"], "Month": ["Feb 2014",  "Apr 2011", "Jan 2011"], "Year": [2014, 2013, 2012, 2011]}';
        temp = JSON.parse(temp);
        $(".sub_category").find('option').remove();
        $.each(temp,function(key, value) 
        {
            if (key == new_category) { 
                var sub_cats = value.toString().split(',');
                for(var i=0;i<sub_cats.length;i++)
                {
                    
              $(".sub_category").append('<option value= "' + sub_cats[i] + '">' + sub_cats[i] + '</option>');
                   
                }
            }
        });
});
});
  $(function() {
    var startDate = new Date(2015,2,30);
    $('#date0').datepicker('setDate',startDate);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use class instead of ID and you can initialise all newly added row with this code datepicker with this code $('body').on('focus',".date-picker", function(){
$(this).datepicker();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the category handler, which need to listen to change event not click event.

Also you need to find the `subcategory` element which is in the same row

```
$(document).on("change", ".category", function() {
    var new_category = $(this).val();
    var temp = '{"Week": ["2014-02-24", "2014-02-17", "2011-01-03"], "Month": ["Feb 2014",  "Apr 2011", "Jan 2011"], "Year": [2014, 2013, 2012, 2011]}';
    temp = JSON.parse(temp);
    var $sub = $(this).closest('tr').find(".sub_category");
    $sub.find('option').remove();
    $.each(temp, function(key, value) {
        if (key == new_category) {
            var sub_cats = value.toString().split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < sub_cats.length; i++) {

                $sub.append('<option value= "' + sub_cats[i] + '">' + sub_cats[i] + '</option>');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/es21rawo/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jquery with $(this), to make the changes only with the respective tr's sub category not with all.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $(document).on("click", "#add_row", function(){
        var datepic = "#date" + i;
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input id = 'date"+
          i+"'  name='name" + i + 
          "' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'/>" 
          + "</td><td><input  name='mail" + 
          i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'>"
          +"</td><td><select class='input category'><option value ='Week'>Week</option><option value = 'Month'>Month</option><option value ='Year'>Year</option></select></select>"
          +"</td>"+"</td><td><select class='input sub_category'></select>"
          +"</td>");

        $(datepic).datepicker();

         $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++; 
     });

     $(document).on("click","#delete_row", function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });
$(document).on("change",".category", function(){
    $this = $(this);
 var new_category = $this.val();
        var temp = '{"Week": ["2014-02-24", "2014-02-17", "2011-01-03"], "Month": ["Feb 2014",  "Apr 2011", "Jan 2011"], "Year": [2014, 2013, 2012, 2011]}';
        temp = JSON.parse(temp);
        $this.parents('tr').find(".sub_category").find('option').remove();
        $.each(temp,function(key, value) 
        {
            if (key == new_category) { 
                var sub_cats = value.toString().split(',');
                for(var i=0;i<sub_cats.length;i++)
                {
                    
              $this.parents('tr').find(".sub_category").append('<option value= "' + sub_cats[i] + '">' + sub_cats[i] + '</option>');
                   
                }
            }
        });
});
});
  $(function() {
    var startDate = new Date(2015,2,30);
    $('#date0').datepicker('setDate',startDate);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
     <tr >
      <th class="text-center">
       #
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Name
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Mail
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Mobile
      </th>      <th class="text-center">
       Mobile
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      <input id = "date0" type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
                   <select name="category" class="input category">                    <option value = "Week">Week</option>
                    <option selected value = "Month">Month</option>
                    <option value = "Year">Year</option></select>
      </td><td>
                   <select name="sub_category" class="input sub_category"></select>
      </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
```